# Spark select item in array by max score

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following `DataFrame` containing an `id` and a Seq of `Stuff` (with an id and score), how do I select the "best" `Stuff` in the array by score?

I'd like **NOT** to use UDFs and possibly work with Spark DataFrame functions only.

```
case class Stuff(id: Int, score: Double)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (1, Seq(Stuff(11, 0.4), Stuff(12, 0.5))), 
    (2, Seq(Stuff(22, 0.9), Stuff(23, 0.8)))
)).toDF("id", "data")

df.show(false)
+---+----------------------+
|id |data                  |
+---+----------------------+
|1  |[[11, 0.4], [12, 0.5]]|
|2  |[[22, 0.9], [23, 0.8]]|
+---+----------------------+

df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = false)
```

I tried going down the route of window functions but the code gets a bit too convoluted. Expected output:

```
+---+---------+
|id |topStuff |
+---+---------
|1  |[12, 0.5]|
|2  |[22, 0.9]|
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spark 2.4 higher-order functions:

```
df
  .selectExpr("id","(filter(data, x -> x.score  == array_max(data.score)))[0] as topstuff")
  .show()
```

gives

```
+---+---------+
| id| topstuff|
+---+---------+
|  1|[12, 0.5]|
|  2|[22, 0.9]|
+---+---------+
```

As an alternative, use window-functions (requires shuffling!):

```
df
  .select($"id",explode($"data").as("topstuff"))
  .withColumn("selector",max($"topstuff.score") .over(Window.partitionBy($"id")))
  .where($"topstuff.score"===$"selector")
  .drop($"selector")
  .show()
```

also gives:

```
+---+---------+
| id| topstuff|
+---+---------+
|  1|[12, 0.5]|
|  2|[22, 0.9]|
+---+---------+
```